# URL to see all Google reviews for a local business

Tags: google-search, google-maps, google-my-business

On Google Search and Google Maps it's possible to see reviews for local business. I would like to bookmark the all reviews listing. How do I find the URL to bookmark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/98204/88163) is now obsolete as Google+ Classic was retired on January 2017, but the good news is that now it's possible to see the reviews of a business from the Google Search and from Google Maps listings.

Google Search

1. Search the business
2. The results page could show a business card on the right panel

[image]

3. Click on the reviews link at the right of the average score.

Google Maps

1. Find the business on Google Maps
2. Open the business listing
3. Go to the review summary section

[image]

4. Click on the reviews link below the average score.